# How get document on mongoose findOneAndDelete middleware using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, middleware, cascade

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am using Typescript with mongoose v5.7.6 to create an API and this API manages users and vehicles so that the vehicle has the user ID and the user has a list of vehicle IDs (mongoose populate usage).

My problem is deleting a vehicle because I need to delete it in the user's vehicle list (cascade effect). I am using the *findByIdAndDelete* method of the vehicle model and have created pre-middleware for *findOneAndDelete* as the documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete).

This *findByIdAndDelete* method triggers *findOneAndDelete* middleware successfully, but how can I get the document that is being deleted to get its attributes as the user ID?

If I use *remove* middleware, I can access the *this* element, but using *findOneAndDelete* middleware *this* does not match the document on Typescript.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to mongoose documentation findOneAndDelete is a query middleware and this keyword in query middleware refers to the query, not the document.

If all you need is just the id of the document in question, then you can get it using `this.getQuery()._id`.

However, if you need more information than the once available in query then you have to query the database for the full document using the current query like so `const document = await Model.find(this.getQuery())`.

document variable will now contain the full document in question.